# Restore an Illuminate Session

Tags: php, session, illuminate

I need to handle some URL redirect for a payment page.
My application uses Illuminate Session and it automatically store the user session.

How can I manually restore a specific session from an anonymous session? Maybe from a session-id passed by queryParam?

In plain PHP it would be:

```
session_id($_GET["mysessId"]);
session_start();
```

but I cannot find the Illuminate documentation to restore a session from a string.

Comment: What do you mean by "anonymous session"?

Comment: A new session not authenticated and probably with a new session-id